# Can't use Scanner.next() and Scanner.nextInt() together

Tags: java

```
Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("how many:");
int n=console.nextInt();
console.nextLine();
String firstName[]=new String[n];
String lastName[]=new String[n];
int zipCode[]=new int[n];
console.useDelimiter("[\t]");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter the first Name"+"Last Name"+"zipcode:");
    firstName[i]=console.next();
    lastName[i]=console.next();
    zipCode[i]=console.nextInt();
    console.nextLine();
}
```

Input with Tabs: `Test  Tst 121`

`firstName[i]` is initialized to `Test`. `lastName[i]` is initialized to `Tst`. But the `zipCode[i]` is not initialized to `121`. It is still prompting for input, but it's not taking anything I enter.

Comment: Try either taking out `console.nextLine()`, or hitting enter again

Comment: You set the delimiter to a tab. So it will keep reading until it reads a tab...

Answer (score 3):

The [`next...()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) methods of a `Scanner` allways first scan the next *token*, and then aim to convert it to the correct type (for instance `int` in the case of `nextInt()`).

Now a token is a sequence of characters that is not a delimiter. Since the only delimiter you've set is a tab (`\t`), it will keep searching for a tab, even if you enter a new line, the search doesn't stop.

Basically there exists two solutions:

**Allowing to use a new line as well:**

```
console.useDelimiter("[\t\r\n]");
```

(and remove `.nextLine()` at the end of the loop). A consequence is that if you separate the first and the last name by a new line, the `Scanner` will not error on this, thus:

```
Test
Tst
121
```

will be parsed as `Test Tst 121` as well, although I don't see much problems with this.

If you really want to disable this, you can **set and reset the delimiter** in the loop. Thus something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter the first Name"+"Last Name"+"zipcode:");
    console.useDelimiter("[\t]");
    firstName[i]=console.next();
    lastName[i]=console.next();
    console.useDelimiter("[\n]");
    zipCode[i]=console.nextInt();
}
```

(but I don't see the added value in this cases).